# simple_html_dom - find() function crashes page if it can't find specific element

Tags: php, error-handling, simple-html-dom, custom-error-handling

im using `simple_html_dom` and i'm using `find()` method to find a specific element on a page. But that element (`div`) is optional. Some pages have, some pages have not. So when `find()` method try to find not existed div all of my script is crashing. On that line it stops. how can I handle `find()`

Im using it like

```
....
....
$html = file_get_html($requestUrl);
$result = $html->find("div[id=searchCategoryContainer] ul li")); //problem is here
.... I cant reach these lines if above div is not existed....
....
....
```

also I tried to use try - catch blocks, still it does not working.

```
try{
    $html = file_get_html($requestUrl);
    $result = $html->find("div[id=searchCategoryContainer] ul li"));
    throw new Exception("there is no element like this!!!");

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping that in a try/catch block.

Comment: you're not capturing the find() call results, so it's a rather pointless call. "find this, then throw away whatever you find".

Comment: @JosephEvans I tried